# How can I handle unique email violation exception in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_new_user(u_name text, u_email text, role_id integer)
RETURNS void as 
$body$
declare 
u_id integer;
begin
--  perform check_email(u_email);
    
    execute 'insert into users (USER_NAME,USER_EMAIL) values ('''|| u_name ||''','''|| u_email||''') RETURNING id;';

    exception
    when unique_violation then 
        raise notice "Email Is Not Unique" ;

    perform insert_role_user(u_email,role_id);

END;
$body$  
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

- Above is the function to create a new user.  The insertion is working good. But when I insert the duplicate email again then it errors.
- I have tried using `unique_violation` exception... But could not properly defined.
- Can someone help me to fix the error?

I used below code snippet to handle exception

```sql
exception
    when unique_violation then 
        raise notice "Email Is Not Unique" ;
```

> Error: `SQL Error [42704]: ERROR: unrecognized exception condition "Email Is Not Unique"¶  Where: compilation of PL/pgSQL function "insert_new_user" near line 11`

Comment: Is it necessary to replace Postgres's unique violation exception with your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, strings are quoted with single quotes.

```
raise notice 'Email Is Not Unique';
```